# Complex use of delegates

Tags: c#

C# newbie here.

In one of my classes (an Entity class, to be precise), I have a delegate that takes in an Entity and another related class:

```
public delegate void FiringFunc(Entity e, BulletFactory fact)
```

and a loop in the Entity class that calls this function every frame (if its defined):

```
FiringFunc firingFunc = null; //defined later
if(firingFunc)
    firingFunc(this, someBulletFactory);
```

As one could probably tell, this is a delegate that serves as a bullet firing function (you would code something like a timer for the bullet, the angles to fire at, etc). However, a thought occurred to me: what if I wanted the bullet to have a *slight* difference, but still remain the same (something like a tad bit slower, a slightly different color, in a different direction, etc). I would have to create another function to serve as the delegate - this seemed wrong to me.

Here is an example of what creating and setting the delegate would look like:

```
Entity e = new Entity( ... )
e.firingFunc = FiringFunctions.SomeFiringFunctionName;
```

Is there a way I could add parameters to this? It would be great if I could do something akin to the following:

```
e.firingFunc = FiringFunctions.SomeFiringFunctionName(someChange1, someChange2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
e.firingFunc = 
    (Entity e, BulletFactory fact) => 
        FiringFunctions.SomeFiringFunctionName(e, fact, "foo", 5);
```

This creates a new anonymous function (the lambda) that calls `FiringFunctions.SomeFiringFunctionName` with the included parameters.

This assumes that FiringFunctions.SomeFiringFunctionName is defined as:

```
public void SomeFiringFunctionName(Entity e, BulletFactory fact, String someString, Int32 someInt) { 
  //...  do whatever here
}
```

Comment: For the benefit of readers, this technique (pre-supplying function arguments) is called "currying" and this example is absolutely the right way to do it in C#.

Comment: Very interesting - I looked at lambda functions as a solution to my problem but did not know how to approach it. Is this equivalent to doing something like:


    `public delegate void FiringFunc(Entity e, BulletFactory fact, param object[] extraStuff);`

and supplying `"foo"` and `5` as the `extraStuff`?

Comment: @LiChE: yes, except in the currying case presented above you wouldn't have to marshal all the parameters into an `object[]` container.  You can have compile-time type safety and intellisense in calling the appropriate function, (which can take different types/number of parameters)

Comment: More or less- I don't have the first argument.  I can modify it to work that way....  done.  I added the Entity `e` and the BulletFactory `fact`.

Comment: @ChrisShain: OP is suggesting modifying the delegate itself, presumably as an alternative to currying, so it could be once again `e.firingFunc = FiringFunctions.SomeFiringFunctionName`, where the definition of `SomeFiringFunctionName` is `(Entity e, BulletFactory fact, param object[] extraStuff)` to handle custom input arguments.

Comment: @ChrisShain Then this is exactly what I need. Thanks a lot!

Err...this is embarassing, but how do I access these extra parameters if the definition of the delegate is `public delegate void FiringFunc(Entity e, BulletFactory fact)`?

Comment: @LiChE: Access them where?  You would require the extra parameters to be passed into `SomeFiringFunctionName`, so they would be accessible from inside the function as arguments.

Comment: @LiChE you don't- they are seamlessly passed through to `FiringFunctions.SomeFiringFunctionName`.  It's signature (in my example above) should be `public void SomeFiringFunctionName(Entity e, BulletFactory fact, String someString, Int32 someInt)`

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a custom interface and take advantage of polymorphism (ya, it needs a better name).

```
public interface IFiringActionProvider
{
    public void Fire(Entity e, BulletFactory fact);
}
```

Then in your same `Entity` class:

```
IFiringActionProvider firingFunc = null; //defined later
if (firingFunc != null)
    firingFunc.Fire(this, someBulletFactory);
```

You can create custom instances in whatever form you'd like, such as:

```
public class CustomColorFiringActionProvider : IFiringActionProvider
{
    private Color color;
    public CustomColorFiringActionProvider(Color c) { this.color = c; }
    public void Fire(Entity e, BulletFactory fact)
    {
        // do something, using color
    }
}
```

Just to add another similar approach (not necessarily better).